# «А может» — постановка запятых

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, вводные-слова

Диалог:

> — Ну у нас в 2023-ем деньги, может, появятся.
> — А может и не появятся.

Во втором высказывании нужна ли запятая (запятые) и куда её (их) поставить тогда, если нужна? Разве при исключении вводных слов предложение не обязано звучать вменяемо и без них?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой И-эх-эх, Артём! Теперь, после твоей правки, мои рекомендации в ответе (*В начале реплики ставится не дефис, а тире*) не имеют никакого смысла. Ты же видел мою правку (или не видел?). Ты же посмотрел мой ответ (или не посмотрел?). Я ведь целенаправленно оставила дефисы, чтобы потом именно на них обратить внимание. Да и запятые, которые ты изничтожил, теоретически можно принять в качестве авторских. Что скаже**шь**? (*Чесслово*, я испытываю необыкновенную *приятность*, обращаясь на *ты*.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос показался мне **интересным и нестандартным,** причем обе его части.

1. **ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (дополнительные сведения по оформлению предложения)

Была предложена следующая **правка:**

*— Ну, у нас в 2023-м деньги, может, появятся.*

*— А может, и не появятся.*

Да, такой вариант возможен, но **необязателен.**

**(1) О слове «ну»**

Это слово может быть **междометием** (обособляется, выделяется паузой и ударением) или **частицей** (не обособляется и не выделяется).

Слово «ну»  – это **побуждение к действию**. Если мы используем междометие, то как бы берем паузу перед размышлением, если же частицу, то говорим уже продуманную мысль. Здесь всё зависит от контекста.

Например (**вариант с частицей**):

*– Вряд ли у кого в ближайшие два года появятся деньги.*

*– **Ну у нас** в 2023-ем деньги, может, появятся.*

*– А может, и не появятся.*

**(2) О сочетании «а может быть»**

В заданном предложении используется  цельное сочетание ***а может быть*** без обособления союза А, но в общем случае возможны **два варианта**:

(1) союз относится к вводному слову в противительных конструкциях следующего вида: *может, появятся, **а может**, не появятся.*

(2) союз относится к структуре предложения, например: *В любом случае, это было не первая мысль, **а, может**, вторая или третья.*

Кроме того, в начале предложения мы часто используем союз А **безо всякого противопоставлении**, а чтобы обозначить переход к новой мысли. Например, можно составить такой диалог, где запятая ставится после союза А;

– Ну у  нас в 2023-м деньги, может, появятся.

–  Ты так думаешь? **А, может**, рано еще  говорить об этом, всякое  возможно.

Также (с союзом НО):  ***Но, может**, рано еще  говорить об этом.*

Вывод: Не следует применять цельное сочетание ***а может быть***, не убедившись в том, что союз А относится именно к вводному слову.

2. **ОТВЕТ** (на второй из заданных вопросов)

"**Разве при исключении вводных слов предложение не обязано звучать вменяемо и без них**?"

Итак, можно ли **изъять** вводное слово из конкретного предложения, то есть обойтись без него, будет ли при этом **нарушен**  смысл?

Многие считают, что с вводными словами можно обращаться именно так – безо всяких последствий убирать из предложения. Почему? Пожалуй, можно назвать две причины.

**Во-первых,** неправильно понимается **определение:** «Вводное слово — слово (или словосочетание), входящее в состав предложения, но не вступающее с его членами в синтаксическую связь. Как правило, выражает отношение говорящего к высказыванию, его оценку, даёт сведение об источнике сообщения или связи с контекстом». Иногда считают, что вводные слова вообще не входят в состав предложения.

**Во-вторых**,  не совсем корректно толкуют **Розенталя**:  «Если же изъятие или перестановка вводного слова невозможна, то запятая после сочинительного союза не ставится (обычно при союзе а)». Здесь говорится о проверке **структуры** предложения,  причем проверяется **возможность перемещения** вводного слова из его конкретной позиции, то есть перестановка в другое место.

Но если убрать вводное слово совсем, то **смысл текста**  будет нарушен. Однако в простых структурах и это не кажется нам очевидным, например: *К сожалению, мы больше не встречались. – К счастью, мы больше не встречались.*

Мы думаем, что здесь-то вводное слово точно можно убрать (лишнее оно как бы), но тогда **отношение** автора к сказанному не будет выраженным, а это важно. Если уберем вводное слово, то  нужно будет  выражать это как-то иначе.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы записала этот диалог следующим образом:
*— Ну, у нас в 2023-м деньги, может, появятся.

— **А может,** и не появятся.*

В начале реплики ставится не дефис, а тире.

Частицу "ну", думаю, стоит отделить запятой.
— **Ну,** у нас есть время подумать и решить, что мы будем делать завтра, ― добавил он. [Анатолий Приставкин. Радиостанция «Тамара» (1994)]

Правильное наращение: **в 2023-м**.
Если перед последней буквой числительного стоит гласная, то наращивается одна буква:
2-й день, 5-я годовщина, в 10-м ряду.
В 1998 году в Канны возили молодое российское кино, **в 1999-м** к фильмам присовокупили музтеатр им. Станиславского... [Неделя 22.08.-2000.08.28 // «Коммерсантъ-Власть», 2000]

Запятая необходима после **а может** (союз + вводное слово).

> 5. Вводное слово (сочетание) отделяется от предшествующего сочинительного союза (как правило, *и, но*) запятой, если вводное слово можно опустить или переставить в другое место предложения без нарушения его структуры...
>    Если же изъятие или перестановка вводного слова невозможна, то запятая после сочинительного союза не ставится (обычно при союзе *а*): ***А впрочем,** беды большой нет, если до Рейна ничего не увидишь* (Герц.)... *Может быть, всё кончится благополучно, **а может быть,** и наоборот.*

На его место у камня заступил кузнец, чернобородое лицо которого было мокрым от пота, **а может,** и от слёз, ― его помощник внизу вроде уже скончался. [Василь Быков. Камень (2002)]

**А может,** и дальше поедем, на тую хоть Камчатку, что ли, рыбу ловить. [Виктор Астафьев. Пролетный гусь (2000)]

[Вводные слова и словосочетания](https://old-rozental.online/punctum_uk.php?pid=3)
[Когда нужны буквенные наращения после цифр?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)